# p:calendar not working if mindate is specified and pattern in "hh:mm a" instead of "HH:mm a"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, time, primefaces, calendar

I am using following  code to show a p:calendar with restricted minimum date.

```
<p:calendar pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"
                    value="#{view.transactionDate}"
                    mindate="#{view.lastTransactionDate}">
</p:calendar>
```

This used to work in primesfaces 3.5

Recently I upgraded to Primefaces 5.3 with JSF-api 2.2.12

The Date Select popup is not showing if I click on the date text box.

If I change the time pattern to `HH:mm`  instead of `hh:mm a`, this works. 
Anyone having anyidea how to fix this?

All the Date Objects are `java.util.Date` and I instantiate using `calendar.getTime()`

Comment: You can always download the source of PF, build a version with non-compressed javascript and then do some debugging client-side. Other would need to do the same if they want to be of any help. Or just take a look at the source and see if you can make out a cause  just from that

Comment: Please add issue here https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues